# Jquery dialog dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm trying to use jquery dialog in my application, but it won't work, it says TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function from mozilla console, this is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
    <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
        <p>
            We're closed during the winter holiday from 21st of December, 2010 until 10th of January 2011.
        </p></div>
</div>

<script >
    $(function() {

        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            position: ['center', 'center'],
            width: 500,
            height: 250,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            buttons: {
                "I've read and understand this": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I'm working on an app which uses other javascript libraries, and to avoid the conflict, I put my dialog script after I use jquery files, but still the same problem. What might be the problem??

Comment: 1) *search* for the error message 2) *load* the plugin correctly (it probably can't load said script resource; check the network activity)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791781/jquery-ui-dialog-is-not-a-function-error , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402531/whats-wrong-with-this-code-dialog-is-not-a-function , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710041/elrte-dialog-is-not-a-function-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since most of javascript libraries are using the dollar sign `$ to operate their functions, including different javascript make conflicts, so to avoid this issue, and to solve the problem, I used this jquery function, and it works

```
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And then use `$j` instead of `$` like this:

```
     $j(function() {

    $j("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        width: 500,
        height: 250,
        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
        buttons: {
            "I've read and understand this": function() {
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

And it works with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that:

1. jquery-ui.js is being loaded by running application through webserver (http). In Firefox's native debugger under tab 'Network' or in Firebug under 'net'.
2. and verify that jquery-ui.js has 'dialog' module

Comment: I tried to use this script from online, and the same problem,<script rc="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
I used my code in seprate page and it works, but when using it in my application it won'r work.

Comment: What all other JS libraries are being used in application? Please share URL if it is hosted, otherwise it is difficult to investigate on presumptions only.