# #jquery dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Following the indications found here: [Jquery dialog dialog is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590468/jquery-dialog-dialog-is-not-a-function)

I imported and used jQuery in my Electron-React-Typescript-Webpack app as follows:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

let jj = jQuery.noConflict();


  jj(document).ready(function () {
    jj('#new-contact').click(function (ev) {
        jj('#contact_dialog').dialog('open');
    });
  });
```

but still I get the error: `TypeError: jj(...).dialog is not a function`

- @types/jquery: ^3.5.5
- @types/jqueryui: 1.12.15
- jquery: ^3.6.0
- node: v14.17.0
- webpack: ^5.23.0

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you import jQueryUI?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you imported JQuery UI

Comment: Looks like you imported jquery twice.  With the 3.6.0 *after* jquery ui 1.12.15. Only include it once, and make it first.  Importing again will overwrite any plugins (ie remove jqueryui)

Comment: Yeah. That post had `<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>` at the top, so you need to import jquery-ui however you're supposed to do it with ES6+ import statements

Comment: Hi all! Thank you very much for your kind help. I installed jquery-ui: ^1.12.1 and imported as `import jqueryui from 'jquery-ui';` Do I have to do do something else?

Comment: @freedomn-m This is what I have done: `import jQuery from 'jquery';
import jQueryUI from 'jquery-ui';
let jj = jQuery.noConflict();` . Did I import jquery twice?

Comment: No idea, not a node developer, but your bulleted list that you provided has jquery ^3.5.5 and jquery ^3.6.0.  What's the bulleted list represent in your question?

Comment: @freedomn-m The bullet list in my question represents the packages installed and thus present in `package.json` file

Comment: So you are installing jquery "package" twice...  does it also represent the order they're installed?  Remove the second jquery should fix your issue.

Comment: I solved following these two indications: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520139/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization . Thank you guys for your kind hints.

Answer (score 0):

I solved following these two indications:

[How to use jQuery UI with React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js)

[jquery ui Dialog: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520139/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization) .

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
//import 'jquery-ui';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.css'
let jj = jQuery.noConflict();

  jj(document).ready(function () {

    jj('#new-contact').click(function (ev) {
        jj('#contact_dialog').dialog().dialog('open');
    });
  });
```

Thank you guys for your kind hints.